# Will iOS app's memory leak leverage any vulnerability?

Tags: ios, security

I have google for this question, and found this [slide](http://www.slideshare.net/OwenGoss/finding-and-fixing-memory-leaks-in-ios-apps-5251292).
[image]

Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Since your device needs memory to "fuel" other applications, eventually your app will get killed. That's why people use instruments, it's not just because it's a best practise. :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course memory leaks can result in your application behaving badly and eventually crashing. This is why you should manage memory carefully (advancing to ARC will probably improve memory leak issues) and also don't forget that you get a chance to clean up when you get memory warnings (via didReceiveMemoryWarning in UIViewController class)

Comment: Of course not, though it is highly recommended as humans tend to make mistakes and are less consistent than the pre-compiler.

Comment: Not saying otherwise, I just felt that your comment was implying that using ARC would make you to properly manage memory. If you don't actually understand how memory management works in iOS, using ARC won't help you.